# Get specific products by id in custom page

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to create a custom page for special offers like buy 2 get 1 free for example.
I want to call some specific products by it's ID inside div.

I've tried to find a solution but I can't.

Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, you can use the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory` class to retrieve specific products by ID in a custom page.

Here's an example of how you can use this class to load a specific product by its ID in a custom controller action:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

class View extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $productFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, ProductFactory $productFactory)
    {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($productId);
        var_dump($product->getData());
    }
}
```

In this example, the custom controller action uses the `getRequest()` method to retrieve the value of the **"id"** parameter from the query string.
It then uses the `create()` method of the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory` to create a new instance of the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`, and the `load()` method to load the product by its ID.
Finally, use `getData()` to get all data of this product

You can also retrieve multiple product by providing the list of product ids.

```
$productIds = [1,2,3];
$products = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $productIds);
```

Please also note that if you are going to use this code in your custom module, you have to make sure that you have declared your custom module in the

> app/code

directory and the routing path is correct. Also make sure to run the setup upgrade command and also flush the cache to see the changes.

Comment: Hi @Jmike.. could you please tell me also how I can execute this code into the custom page ?

Comment: @Jmike shouldn't we use product repository instead of collection directly?